# is there a way to render a scene with wireframe blending effect in 3DS Max?

Tags: 3d, 3ds-max

is there a way to render a scene with wireframe blending effect in 3DS Max?

Like this or something similar to this effect - 
[image]

Something like this is possible using blender

[image]

Is 3DS Max capable of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides that this is not the fastest method, is more interactive that any other method.

First, render you image as you would normally do. Then create a **Standard Material** and **check Wire** under the Shader Basic Parameters. Replace this new material with the one your geometry has.

[image]

**Rerender** the Image, save it and compose both results with a Gradient as a **Transparency Mask** and choose your desired Blend Mode: Add, Screen, Multiply ...

### That's it!

Comment: Thanks. My PC is a little slow so I'll check it out and see what it comes up.